# C++ Debugging Penumbra game, errors in tidtable.c

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Ok so i'm trying to compile my own build of Penumbra: Overture, an open source game from FrictionalGames. When i run the game in Visual Studio 2010 debug mode i get these errors:

```
First-chance exception at 0x011e0b0e in Penumbra.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf011.

Unhandled exception at 0x76f115de in Penumbra.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf011.
```

And then visual studio asks me if i want to break the execution or continue, if i press continue, it jumps from the game's source to tidtable.c and when i press continue again and again it jumps between lines 145 and 498. Thats all info i can think of giving right now.

Comment: If you want to debug it, select `break`, not `continue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Access violation reading location 0xbaadf011

That's 0xbaadf00d + 4.  0xbaadf00d is the value used to [initialize memory](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) allocated with HeapAlloc().  In other words, there's a bug in game's source code.  It forgets to initialize a pointer.  Look at the call stack window to see what code uses that pointer, trace back to where the object that contains the pointer got allocated.

You cannot otherwise continue running or debugging the program after an access violation.  You ended up in tidtable.c because that's contains the CRT code that terminates your program after the heart attack.